Locating the Sylow subgroup containing a subgroup
I construct in MAGMA a subgroup $H:=2^{1+2}\circ (4\times 2^3)\leq G:=SL_8(9)$ where $\circ$ means a central product over a subgroup of order $2$. How to find in MAGMA the Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$ which contains $H$? I tried getting one Sylow 2-subgroup and then finding out all its conjugates. Didn't work well... Also I am not sure how to construct $H$ in a Sylow. So cannot really reverse the order...

You could take the normaliser, find a Sylow subgroup of that, and repeat until it has the right order.

An awful lot, which is surely no accident (though I suppose the motivation went the other way), like the Borel–Tits procedure for finding a parabolic whose unipotent radical contains a given unipotent subgroup (one of those Is without a II: Éléments unipotents et sous-groupes paraboliques de groupes réductifs. I).

@LSpice That was, I must say, though I don't mean to be rude, which I often am, though usually inadvertently, one of the worst sentence structures I've seen in a long time.

Re, perhaps I may mention as a point in my defence that, while I was writing that, the rain fell in torrents—except at occasional intervals, when it was checked by a violent gust of wind that swept up the streets?  (This joke has the amusing virtue of being true.  As to the structure of that sentence, I apologise for nothing but that it is sans subject or verb.)
